# np.linalg.det() is the unique way to calc a matrix determinant?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If you just need to work with clasic 2D matrices, it's so fine to use `numpay.mat` because of their small and intuitive atributes:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.mat('1 2; 3 4')   # Matlab-like creating nomenclature.. cool!
y = np.mat('5 6; 7 8')

print(x.I)      # inverse matrix... cool!
print(x.T)      # transpose matrix... cool!
print(x*y)      # matrix multiplication... cool!
print(np.linalg.det(x))   # it's so tired to have to write all this to obtain the determinant!
```

Is there any fancy way to aboid writting "np.linalg.det(x)" to calc a determinant?

Comment: Talk about programmer's lazyness :)  While `np.matrix` was included for wayward MATLAB programmers, its use is discouraged these days.  `x@y` works for both `np.matrix` and `ndarray`.  `.T` as shortcut to `transpose` also works for both.  But `np.matrix` is limited to 2d (as was the case in the original MATLAB).

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a `det` variable for shortcut because functions are first-class objects:

```
>>> det = np.linalg.det
>>> det(x)
-2.0000000000000004
```

or perhaps better with [`from ... import ...`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#from):

```
>>> from numpy.linalg import det
>>> det(x)
-2.0000000000000004
```